# How to edit the HTML of a webpage

Tags: html, vba, double-quotes

After posting my question, I found the solution, so instead of deleting it, I rather post the solution. It may be helpful for someone else.

I want to modify some elements in an HTML webpage that I have opened with VBA as an IE Object.
Specifically, I want to change the background color of a title element (the day number in a multiline calendar), so that it is more easily distinguished from the other day numbers. The server sends all day numbers with a dark grey background but I want to see today's number with a bright yellow background on my screen.
I found the relevant HTML code is like this:

```
<th class="daynumber">24</th>
<th class="daynumber">25</th>
<th class="daynumber">26</th>
<th class="daynumber">27</th>
```

and in VBA I can retrieve day 26 with

```
a = IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml
```

Then I use

```
IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("titel oben daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml = "<th>bgcolor=""yellow"">26</th>"
```

to edit the code after retrieving the element. 
The first problem I encountered was how to created a text variable with nested quotes. This is resolved by replacing the inner quotes with double-quotes.
The second was that during my trials extra HTML lines were created, but I understood now that I cannot repeat the second line without repeating also the first.
So the complete code is (after opening the webpage as an IE Object):

```
a = IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("titel oben daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml
IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("titel oben daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml = "<th bgcolor=""yellow"">26</th>"
```

where 25 and 26 will have to be replaced by a variable concatenated to the text.

Comment: Just use single quotes inside the double quotes instead. Or in this particular example, you dont need them at all around `yellow`

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this but it did not compile. Maybe I did something wrong. Using dual quotes ""..."" worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the following to compile the above properly.

```
IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("titel oben daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml = "<th>bgcolor=""yellow"">26</th>"
```

Note the Double Double Quotes before and after Color code.

Or Just the below as suggested by braX

```
IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("titel oben daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml = "<th>bgcolor=yellow>26</th>"
```

Comment: or just `"<th>bgcolor=yellow>26</th>"` as they are optional.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please choose the answer as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use only `"` as a top-tier, as i imagine most people do.
For Example

```
IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("titel oben daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml = "<th>bgcolor=yellow>26</th>"
```

But you can also do like,

```
IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("titel oben daynumber").Item(25).outerHtml = "<th>bgcolor=""yellow"">26</th>"
```

Comment: thank you all for your replies. They came in so fast that I saw them only after editing my text because I had found the solution with the "" ..."" by myself after posting the question. Anyway, I will now try also your other solutions. I did not know that yellow can also go without quotes..